# Where do I look for the database script generated from JPA Entities?

Tags: mysql, jpa, jboss

I am having a few errors like the following when I deploy my JPA entities into JBoss.

---

18:34:53,462 ERROR [SchemaExport] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Group (id)' at line 1
18:34:53,684 ERROR [SchemaExport] Unsuccessful: alter table Value add index FK4E9A15132C855E3 (groupId), add constraint FK4E9A15132C855E3 foreign key (groupId) references Group (id)

---

Where do I look for the generated database script to create the tables ?I would like to take a look at it to debug my errors

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you may have set your SQL dialect wrong. Also, there is no standard way to get an SQL script with JPA; you have to directly use methods specific to the underlying JPA implementation for that.

Comment: @andri...thanks for the reply. Are you aware of any such JPA api methods? I couldn't find any.

Comment: Thanks all. I fixed it. I was using some reserved words to name some of my tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use Group as a table name. GROUP is a SQL keyword, so we need to rename it.

Do the following

```
@Entity
@Table(name="GROUPI") // or other name
public class Group {

}
```

regards,